# back button wont work.. Iphone

Tags: iphone

I have 2 page controls in my app, one for category and when i click details button of that category other page control comes.
I have pushed the first view controller and used present modal view controller. Now a need to go back to the home page from the category page control but the view did load and view will appear wont work. That is where i have added my navigation bar programmatically. is there any way i can call them?

i am new to iphone programming. Please help me if you can....

Thankyou

Comment: What's the code that's supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use delegate.**

Set the object that created your new view controller as delegate. When you presenting your view controller add it to navigation bar. Setup your view controller with cancel/done buttons and set them up to pass the messages to delegate.

When user selects cancel/done the delegate method is called. Delegate can then dismiss the view controller.

See the example in [View Controller programming guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1).

You'll have to setup the buttons and call to delegate when you create your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used "present model view controller"

then you required to use "dismis model view controller" instead of using "pop view controller" for going back...